# Time.sleep() on ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

I am using ChromeDriver for some web scraping using Python. 
My code uses `browser.find_element_by_xpath` but I have to include `time.sleep(3)` between clicks/input because I need to wait for the webpage to load before I can execute the next line of code.

Was wondering if anyone knows the best way to do this? Perhaps a feature that can automatically execute the next line instantly when the browser loads instead of waiting for an arbitrary number of seconds?

Thanks!

Comment: See documentation here :  https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with `explicit wait` using `expected_conditions` as shown below.

**Imports need:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Then you can wait for the element to be present before interacting.

```
# waiting for max of 30 seconds, if element present before that it will go on to the next line.
ele = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"xpath_goes_here")))
ele.click() # or what ever the operation like .send_keys()
```

This way the application will dynamically wait until the element is present. Update the time from 30 seconds if required based on your application.

Also you can use different location strategies when checking for the element presence eg: `By.CSS_SELECTOR/By.ID/By.CLASS_NAME`

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept by clicking on the check mark in my answer on the left hand side for the befit of future reader/helpers.

Comment: it's working much faster now, thank you! on a side note, i read some articles here that CSS works faster than xpath on Chrome, which is the browser I am currently using. My project involves web scraping on flight prices. Do you think it's necessary to change my code to replace xpath with CSS?

Comment: Always suggestible to use CSS where ever it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with a function for this cases that add robustness to the script. For instance for finding an element by xpath:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC


def findXpath(xpath,driver):
    actionDone = False
    count = 0
    while not actionDone:
        if count == 3:
            raise Exception("Cannot found element %s after retrying 3 times.\n"%xpath)
            break
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, waitTime).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
            actionDone = True
        except:
            count += 1
    sleep(random.randint(1,5)*0.1)
    return element
```

Let me know of this works for you!

Comment: Not sure, why we need this complex logic when you can handle this simply by using `WebDriverWait` that you used in your `try` block. If you want to wait for longer time (3 times) then you can simply say `waitTime*3`.

Comment: In my experience with selenium, sometimes some web driver elements are found, but then destroyed by the website causing the web driver to doesn't  found the element. This logic gives a retry attempt to the elements and helps to reduce code.

Comment: when you say `destroyed` are you talking about `stale element exception`? Usually, selenium will refresh the element references each time the page loads (sometimes clicking on a element on the page might refresh the page internally) in that case you can't use the old references. Even, in that case if you are using the `.find_element` still selenium will find the element based on latest references. You will get the stale element issue  only when you are pointing to the older `element` reference like `ele` in this case after elements reference update caused issue but not `.find_element`

Comment: No, actually I refer in the fly, specially when some javascript is updating the values  on website you are looking.

Comment: thank you for that! i am aware that webdriver `.get()` will wait for a page to load by default. Is there a way to click an element instantly when it is available? I used `.element_to_be_clickable(xxxx)` but it's after `.get()` but it's not working as expected.